# Excel conditional formatting graded color scale only valid inside the range

Tags: excel, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I tried to search for a similar problem but I haven't found one.
Basically, I want to do use this rules for the formatting:

- value from 1 to 89: graded color bar from red to orange;
- value from 90 to 94: yellow;
- value from 95 to 105: green;
- value from 106 to 110: yellow;
- value from 111 to 200: graded color bar from orange to red;

[image: rules of conditional formatting]

The problem is that the graded color bar rules apply also for values outside of the range that I have input.
So for example, with the rules set up in that way as in picture, the value 200 will be in orange, because the rule before the last will apply also for value outside the range and greater that 89.

Is there any advice to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: *The problem is that the graded color bar rules apply also for values outside of the range that I have input.* Why is this a problem? Each formatting rule has a range where it is applied. If you want certain rules to have different ranges, then just change the ranges for those rules where you want different ranges.

Comment: ok, but with the rules in the pics, I have that, for example, the value 200 is in orange and not in red, because the rule before the last said that values from 1 to 89 should be from red to orange, and so all the values greater than 89 wil be orange.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. Sounds like your rules are set up incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

I assume all your numbers are integers. If the entire range is 1 to 200 (both inclusive) you could skip two CF rules by applying 'standard' yellow fill to all cells. If you might have numbers less than `1` or more than `200` a single formula rule for yellow should serve:

```
=OR(AND(B8>105,B8<111),AND(B8>89,B8<95))
```

One for green:

```
=AND(B8>94,B8<106)
```

And 2-Color Scales with Minimum Number `1` to Maximum Number `89` for Red to Orange and Minimum Number `111` to Maximum Number `200` for Orange to Red.

All rules are exclusive so no need for Stop If True and their order does not matter.